# Unable to start rails server: Segmentation fault, but able to start server through Zeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to start the server

```
/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

But if i run `zeus start` and `zeus server`, it starts up without a hitch. Any ideas?

## edit

which rails gives me `/usr/bin/rails`

and which ruby gives me `/Users/sherwyn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby`

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants the solution it's

```
bundle exec rails server
```

I have no idea why it works but

```
rails server
```

works fine afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Yourr Gemset might not be compiled for the version of ruby you are using

Comment: so if my rvm version is 2.0.0-p353 and my gemfile states 2.0.0, it will conflict? how do i fix this ?